# Why my args[1] doesn't work in this case in discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

The code works normal for args[0] but doesn't work for args[1]. Can you guys explain this for me or give me a source that I can find out my mistake? Thanks for your help

```js
bot.on('message', message =>{

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split("  ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'ping':
            message.reply('Pong!');
            break;
        case 'website':
            message.reply('www.facebook.com')
            break;
        case 'info':
            if(args[1] === 'version'){
                message.reply('Version ' + version);
            }else{
                if(args[1] === 'author'){
                    message.reply('Vikoaz');
               }else{
                   message.reply('Invalid')
               }
            }
        break;
        case 'clear':
            if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Error')
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
        break;


    }
```

When I write !info version in Discord the bot doesn't reply Version + version. Nothing happens. If just !info the bot replies Invalid.

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please copy and paste your code into your question instead of posting a photo of it. It makes it a lot easier for other people to help you.

Comment: And please paste an example input (`message.content`) alongside the actual error, is `args[1]` `undefined` or ?

Comment: By the way, you can use [else if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Description) like `else if (args[1] === 'author') {...} else {...}` instead of `else {if (args[1] === 'author') {...} else  {...}}`. This isn't the problem though.

Comment: ensure you have an array of length 2 to access args[1] , if length is is 1 you will get error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 spaces here: `.split("  ")`. Make that 1 space:

```js
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
```

With 2 spaces, if `message.content` is `'!info version'` `args` would be `['info version']`, which  is why it wasn't working.

Comment: That help me a lot. Thanks for your help and your advice too

Comment: @DdankDdum You're welcome! If this fixed your problem, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the tick. That indicates that your question is solved and it also gives you 2 reputation.